# What does "volatile write semantics" mean?

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile

What could happen, if we would omit setArray in set method?

Could you write code, even using some helper semaphore, that would show necessiti of using this volatile write and calling of setArray ?

Below code comes from CopyOnWriteArrayList.java

```
final transient Object lock = new Object();    
private transient volatile Object[] array;
public CopyOnWriteArrayList() { setArray(new Object[0]); }

public E set(int index, E element) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        Object[] elements = getArray();
        E oldValue = elementAt(elements, index);

        if (oldValue != element) {
            int len = elements.length;
            Object[] newElements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, len);
            newElements[index] = element;
            setArray(newElements);
        } else {
            // Not quite a no-op; ensures volatile write semantics
            setArray(elements);  // <------ what is it actually for ? ------
                                 // what If it would me ommited ?
        }
        return oldValue;
    }
}    

final void setArray(Object[] a) {
    array = a;
}
```

Comment: Gosling is famous for [cryptic comments](http://donhopkins.com/home/archive/emacs/skull-and-crossbones.txt). I suggest you *carefully* read [JLS-8.3.1.4. `volatile` Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4)

Answer (score 0):

"Volatile write" semantics here means a new array will be published safely. You may noticed, that there is a method

```
final Object[] getArray() {
    return array;
}
```

which means you can read just published array without any synchronization (this is the whole point of CopyOnWriteArrayList). If there is possibility of concurrent read and write of object in java, you **have** to use `volatile` keyword. Otherwise, object may be published inconsistently. If object is published in that way, some of its field may not be properly initialized.

For excessive amount of information on topic, I suggest you to read [this great article](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/)